# Understanding CheckStyle JavadocMethod Rule

Tags: java, checkstyle

```
/**
* set myMethod
* @param param1
* @param param2
* @param param3
* @param param4
*/
public void myMethod(ClassAA param1, ClassBB param2, HashMap<String, String> param3, Set<String> param4) {code}
```

When I run the checkstyle on above code, It tells me that there are errors like this 
"Expected @param tag for 'param1'". 
I would like to understand , why checkstyle is reporting them as error, when the tags is there.

Thanks

Comment: add the description of variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like:

```
/**
* set myMethod
* @param param1 the AA to use for extracting the reference data
* @param param2 BB processing options
* @param param3 table of user parameters
* @param param4 set of active keywords
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation missing in your documentation - describe the parameters.

Comment: params are in documenatation already, as i have shared. Not sure what other documentation i need to provide can you send me solution, kindly